# VBA Script to Extract data every 30s Interval

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of voltage outputs and the time stamps at which they were recorded. For some background, my test increments a voltage by 1mV every 30s from 0 - 5V. The system reads every second or so, it can be inconsistent. The sheet has over 70000 rows but I only need just over 5000.

So far I have used =RIGHT(TEXT(A1, "hh:mm:ss"),2) to extract the seconds from the time. Unfortunately, the timestamps are always perfectly every 30s so I can't simply filter for every 0s and 30s. Sometimes 30s is skipped and it reads at say 35s.

How would I create a VBA script that extracts the increments at every 30s interval and if there is no perfect 30s jump, select the closest match to it (i.e. 29 or 31)?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that you can make a straight-forward "filter" for this.  However, you could write a VBA macro (or an Array function) that would either 1) copy the appropriate 5000 rows out to a different sheet, or 2) set a flag column for the 5000 out of the 70,000 that should be selected/filtered for. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung how do you recommend I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe [MRound](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mround-function-c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) can be useful here. You could round all time stamps to multiple of 30 or 0, and then select them

Comment: I don't think this would work very well because if there is an interval where there already is a perfect 30s, it would round up 29 to 30 and skew my final number of rows... The goal is to be able to match the test data to the theoretical data showing the exact increments compared to the real data.

Comment: Sorry, this wasn't the kind of thing that I could answer off the top of my head.  I have posted an answer that should work as an array function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think that the following will work.  Note that this needs to be entered as an Excel formula array in the Flags output column, with the function's input parameter being the corresponding column that contains the times.  (So the output column's formula should look like: `{=FlagEvery30Sec(D2:D36)}`)

```
' Returns 1 if the corresponding row should be used, and 0 otherwise
Public Function FlagEvery30Sec(SourceTimes As Range) As Integer()
    Dim Times() As Variant
    Dim Flags() As Long
    
    ' get the source values
    Times = SourceTimes
    
    ' set the output values array to the same size
    Dim First As Long, Last As Long
    First = LBound(Times, 1)
    Last = UBound(Times, 1)
    ReDim Flags(First To Last, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim curr As Long, prev As Long
    prev = First
    curr = First
    Flags(curr, 1) = 1
    curr = curr + 1
    
    Dim currTime As Date
    Dim currSecs As Double, prevSecs As Double, lastFlagSecs As Double
    lastFlagSecs = CDbl(Times(curr, 1)) * 24 * 60 * 60
    
    While curr <= Last
        Flags(curr, 1) = 0    ' assume not flagged, change later
        currSecs = CDbl(Times(curr, 1)) * 24 * 60 * 60
        If (currSecs - lastFlagSecs) >= 30 Then
            If ((currSecs - lastFlagSecs) - 30) <= (30 - (prevSecs - lastFlagSecs)) Then
                Flags(curr, 1) = 1
                lastFlagSecs = currSecs
            Else
                Flags(prev, 1) = 1
                lastFlagSecs = prevSecs
            End If
        End If
        
        prevSecs = currSecs
        prev = curr
        curr = curr + 1
    Wend
    
    FlagEvery30Sec = Flags
End Function
```

Note that there are basically two approaches to this:

1. Take the first timestamp, mark off every 30 seconds, then find the entry that is closest to each mark and flag it.  Or,
2. Take the first timestamp and find the following entry that is closest to 30 seconds after it.  Then take that entry's time as the base timestamp and find the next entry that is closest to 30 seconds after that.  Repeat this until you reach the end.

My function above uses the second method.  You should note that this can drift though and the final result may be more or less marks than TotalSeconds/30.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much! The only problem I encountered is that it would act up and give "#VALUE" to every flag if I calculated over the entire 70335 rows, I have to split it up in section of maximum 30000 rows and then paste over in a new sheet. Thanks again!

Comment: This really needs to use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Otherwise as @QuadeHowald experienced, `First = LBound(Times, 1)` and `Last = UBound(Times, 1)` will throw an Overflow error if `SourceTimes` contains more than 32,767 rows.

Comment: @BigBen Right you are, I forgot the integers are 16 bit in VBA.

Comment: @QuadeHowald FYI, I have corrected the code.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The data outputted seems to be slightly off, after filtering, I end up with 4998 rows of data but I am looking for 5004. Would it be possible to take the mark off every 30s only base on time 0? So increment one is time 0 +30s, the increment 2 is time 0 + 60s and so on. Perhaps this might help with this... Thank you!

Comment: @RBarryYoung I was wondering if you could help adjust the code a little bit? How would it change if we went forward with method 1 where the 30s are marked based on the very first value and using 60s increments instead? Your help is really appreciated!